# Error handling "URL file-access is disabled..."

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm getting these 2 errors:

> **Warning**: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in
>   /home/content/.../wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 4035
>
> **Warning**: file_get_contents(http://www.mysite.net/...y-1.7.2.min.js)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable
>   wrapper could be found in
>   /home/content/.../html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line
>   4035

Here's line 4035

```
$myFile=file_get_contents(get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js");
```

Is this just a permissions issue on the server? How might I wrap this function to prevent the error and exit out to a useful message?

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is turned of in php.ini. Turn it on or contact your server admins, who may have a reason for _not_ permitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` (if you want to load remote resources using `include`) in your php.ini config file. Also, you can try adding this to `.htaccess` but I don't think it will work if you're running php as an apache module - it's not suppose to override this setting...

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```